# How do I make conditions based on list options?

Tags: lists, conditionals

Specifically, I need to write a command which changes its behavior if the option `wide` is turned on... So I need some kind of condition

```
if wide is on then do this, else do that.
```

Can somebody point out how to do such condition in TeX ?

Pseudocode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[wide]
\item
\if@wide \do "print{this list is wide} and change \rightmargin to 3cm"
\else \do "print{this list is not wide} and change \rightmargin to 2cm"
\fi
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `wide` option doesn't activate a different branch of code, it just changes some internal parameters of `enumitem`. It's easy to make the code detect if the option was used, but I think you won't get anything useful here. What exactly do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I need to change some lengths and variables based on if this option is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook into the definition of the `wide` option and make your conditional true. The value of the conditional is reset after the environment.

Note also that the `wide` option takes an argument. If you pass none, then `\parindent` is used (*i.e.,* `\begin{itemize}[wide]` is the same as `\begin{itemize}[wide=\parindent]`).

However you should not try to change `enumitem`'s internal parameters (they are internal for a reason) in the document. You should stick to the key-value interface it provides.

Anyhow, here it is:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifwide
\patchcmd\enitkv@enumitem@wide
  {\enit@align@left}% <- Search
  {\widetrue\enit@align@left}% <- Replace
  {}{\FailedToPatch}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[wide]
\item
\ifwide \texttt{wide} was used
\else \texttt{wide} was NOT used
\fi
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item
\ifwide \texttt{wide} was used
\else \texttt{wide} was NOT used
\fi
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way you could use list styles, contained in macro settings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}

\newenvironment{styledlist}[1][]
{\expandafter\itemize\expandafter[#1]}{\enditemize}

\def\widelist{wide,itemindent=15pt,label=*,leftmargin=-1cm,rightmargin=-1cm}
\def\narrowlist{itemindent=15pt,label=++,leftmargin=1cm,rightmargin=1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{styledlist}[\widelist]
\item \lipsum[4]
\end{styledlist}

\begin{styledlist}[\narrowlist]
\item \lipsum[4]
\end{styledlist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, I meant... I need this condition for my other macro command. I don't want to complicate my question with those so I wrote it like that... I just need a switch which would have different behaviour based on if option is wide on or not. I need to change some variables and lengths specifically...

Comment: @Lust_For_Love See my edit, if that helps.